# Replace multiple characters within a string with a single replace

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to replace multiple characters with one `replace`. I am trying the following:

```
var a = "[info]";
a = a.replace(/([|])/g,""); // Want to replace [ and ]
```

But the above snippet doesn't work. It gives out the same string without any replacement. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you want to remove them anywhere in the string or only at start/end?

Comment: @downvoter Would appreciate any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could skip the group and escape the open bracket, because the open bracket is used to open a character class.

```js
console.log("[i[nf]o]".replace(/\[|]/g, ''));     // all
console.log("[i[n]fo]".replace(/^\[|]$/g, '')); // only at start and end
```

Comment: `]` doesn't have to be escaped.

Comment: @Kinduser: It is not actually an error at any rate. Most people escape it just in case, to play it safe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`[` square bracket has to be escaped. `]` doesn't have to, but it's a good practice to escape it - just in case. (Thanks to Wiktor for pointing it out).

```js
var a = "[info]";
a = a.replace(/(\[|\])/g, '');

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Alright, but why didn't it replace `]`?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Hit the `run code snippet` button and you will see that it's replaced. Only `info` word remains.

Comment: Yes it does. But even if `[` was not escaped, why was `]` not replaced?

Comment: @SuhailGupta I've added a short note about it. The `[` bracket is a special character in RegExp, it **has to be** escaped, if not - it won't be matched (replaced). The `]` bracket is not a special character and it will be replaced  if escaped or not.

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape `[` because they are special characters:

```
a.replace(/\[|]/g, "");
```

Thanks to @Wiktor-Stribiżew

Here is the snippet for test reasons:

```js
console.log("[info]".replace(/\[|]/g, ''));
```

Comment: Note that a  `]` is not a special character outside a character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, Tested & updated

Comment: I would use a totally different pattern - `.replace(/[[\]]+/g, '')`. But it's just me.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting an `|` between `[` and `]` so it will act as char class and check for occurrence of `|`

Simply escape the starting one

```js
var a = "[info]";
a = a.replace(/(\[|])/g,"");
console.log(a);
```

String that will matched by regex you write is

```js
var a = "[i|nfo]";
a = a.replace(/([|])/g,"");
console.log(a);
```

As you can see above, the `|` is replaced.